# Typescript - forEach iterate objects and arrays

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript

In constant "x" can be one or more "user objects". "User object" has some atributes, one of them is "profession". User can have one or more "profession". So "user" keeps one or more profession Ids. I want profession ids from each user object to get to professionIdsToDelete - so I iterate each "user" object and in them iterate "profession".

When I use console log in "professionIdsToDelete" I get for example  "single id" and "pair of ids":

(2) [Array(1), Array(2)]0: ["NehR5yNTdHYR82oGi"]1: (2) ["RQyJfQxaixWETK8ky", "8t35cao62W6Nz5LqY"]length: 2__proto__: Array(0)

I need this: ["NehR5yNTdHYR82oGi", "RQyJfQxaixWETK8ky", "8t35cao62W6Nz5LqY"]

What I do wrong? Thnx for advice.

**Code an sample of userInArray from console:**

```
removeUser() {

    let professionIdsToDelete = [];

    this.usersToDeleteSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('usersByUserIds', this.selectedUsers).subscribe(() => {

      const x = Users.find({ 
        _id: { 
            $in: this.selectedUsers 
        }
      }).fetch();
      console.log(x);

      x.forEach((userInArray) => {
        let professionsInUser = [];
        professionsInUser.push(userInArray.profession);

        professionsInUser.forEach((professionId) => {
          professionIdsToDelete.push(professionId);
        })

        console.log(professionIdsToDelete);

      })



    ► {_id: "DXZNwqCy8ptz5HCYH", createdAt: Wed Jan 17 2018 16:19:30 GMT+0100 (CET), services: {…}, emails: Array(1), profile: {…}, …}
     createdAt: Wed Jan 17 2018 16:19:30 GMT+0100 (CET) {constructor: ƒ}
        email: "xxx"
    ► emails: [{…}]
    ► profession: Array(2)
        0:"RQyJfQxaixWETK8ky"
        1:"8t35cao62W6Nz5LqY"
        length: 2
      __proto__: Array(0)
    ► profile:{name: "Zdenek", surename: "Flaksa", phone: "53455", buildingId: "nwXxEg2FAjBqZX9zH"}
    ► services:{password: {…}, resume: {…}}
       _id:"DXZNwqCy8ptz5HCYH"
    ► __proto__:Object
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the JSON of the `userInArray`?

Comment: Your code looks good. As mentioned above. Please provide the actual structure of userInArray.

Comment: sample of userInArray added.